# Javascript - Add more button function with 2 Dynamic Select Tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 Select Boxes (Class & Section). When I select a class, the 2nd Select box gets the dynamic list of related Sections from another file through AJAX. It is working well. I added (Add More Class Btn) with JS function which creates the same 2 select boxes (Class & Section). After selecting the Class, I'm not able to get the related Sections because of same id.

Here is my **PHP** Code:

```
        <?php
            include('dbConfig.php');
            $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM classes ");
            $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
        ?>

        <div class="input_fields_wrap">
            <button class="add_field_button btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add More Classes</button><br><br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Class</label>
                    <select name="class[]" id="class" class="form-control" style="width:150px;" required >
                        <option value="">Select Class</option>
                        <?php
                        if($rowCount > 0){
                            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
                                echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['class'].'</option>';
                            }
                        }else{
                            echo '<option value="">No Class Available</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select><br>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Section</label>
                    <select id="section" name="section[]" class="form-control" style="width:150px;" required >
                    <option value="">Select Class first</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div><br>
        </div>
```

Here is my **JS** Code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 0; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append(
            '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><label>Class</label><select name="class[]" id="class" class="form-control" style="width:150px;" required ><option value="">Select Class</option><?php $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM classes "); $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
                    if($rowCount > 0){
                        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
                            echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['class'].'</option>';
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo '<option value="">No Class Available</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </select></div><div class="col-md-6"><label>Section</label><select id="section" name="section[]" class="form-control" style="width:150px;" required ><option value="">Select Class first</option></select></div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div><br>'); //add box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#class').on('change',function(){
            var Class = $(this).val();
            if(Class){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'get_sections.php',
                    data:'id='+Class,
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#section').html(html);
                    }
                }); 
            }else{
                $('#section').html('<option value="">Select Class first</option>');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my **get_sections.php** Code:

```
include('dbConfig.php');

if (isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])){
  //Get all Section Data
  $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sections WHERE class_id = ".$_POST['id']." ORDER BY section ASC");

  //Count total number of rows
  $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

  //Display Section list
  if($rowCount > 0){
    echo '<option value="">Select Section</option>';
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
      echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['section'].'</option>';
    }
  }else{
    echo '<option value="">No Section Available</option>';
  }
}
```

Help me please with the fetching of JS generated Selected Class Sections.

Comment: _I'm not able to get the related Sections because of same id._ So use a class instead of ID and search for "delegation jquery"

Comment: Kindly can you tell the method, I have no knowledge of JS or Jquery :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Here you use '#class' multiple time. Don't use same 'ID' multiple
   time.
2. If you add/append html by jquery operation, same jquery function not working for newly added html. But a simple change can solve the problem.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(document).on('change','#class',function(){
           var Class = $(this).val();
           if(Class){
               $.ajax({
                   type:'POST',
                   url:'get_sections.php',
                   data:'id='+Class,
                   success:function(html){
                       $('#section').html(html);
                   }
               }); 
           }else{
               $('#section').html('<option value="">Select Class first</option>');
           }
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: I have issue with the assigning of ID, I have no idea how to assign the ID so as to get the data in select box

Comment: Use Class instead of ID.

Your Code :**$('#class').on('change',function(){
   // operation
})**

Use This : **$(document).on('change',',class',function(){
    // operation
})**

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple as you cant expect ,first you have to generate the random unique id when you (Add more class & section)

```
  var uniqueId = function() {
      return 'id-' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 16);
    }
```

i have update code by inserting the uniqueId() function which will generate the unique id for element and inject into the directive (id="+un_id+") and added getlist() function on Onchange event

```
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
var un_id=uniqueId ();
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append(
            '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><label>Class</label><select name="class[]" id="+un_id+" class="form-control" onchange="getlist(this)" style="width:150px;" required ><option value="">Select Class</option><?php $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM classes "); $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
                    if($rowCount > 0){
                        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
                            echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['class'].'</option>';
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo '<option value="">No Class Available</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </select></div><div class="col-md-6"><label>Section</label><select id="section" name="section[]" class="form-control" style="width:150px;" required ><option value="">Select Class first</option></select></div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div><br>'); //add box
        }
    });
```

now you will need to identify the select element uniquely when you select the value from custom select element

```
function getlist(obj){
     var Class =obj.val();
                if(Class){
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'get_sections.php',
                        data:'id='+Class,
                        success:function(html){
                            $('#section').html(html);
                        }
                    }); 
                }else{
                    $('#section').html('<option value="">Select Class first</option>');
                }
            });
}
```

see this one live example

```js
var uniqueId = function() {
      return 'id-' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 16);
    }
function add(){
var id=uniqueId();
 document.getElementById("custom").innerHTML +="<select id='"+id+"' onchange='getname(this)' ><option value='india'>India</option><option value='mumbai'>Mumbai</option></select>"; 
}

function getname(obj){
alert(obj.value);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="add()">ADD</button>
<div id="custom">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: same process will run for section (select tag)genrate unique id for section also

Comment: i updated my code as you said, now it is not working at all

Comment: did you check the id in ( html inspect) is it generating uniquely ?

Comment: see ,i have updated with small live example it may help you

Answer (score 0):

1. You repeat yourself in the HTML and the jQuery - the classes are the same and you should CLONE the div instead.
2. If you do NOT use id="class" you can clone as many as you want
3. Class is a reserved word. Don't use it as a variable

change `id="class" class="form-control"` to 
`class="form-control classSel"`

Here is a SUGGESTION of how to change the code. You may have to fix typos or syntax errors. I cannot test my code without your backend.

```js
$(function() {
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var x = 0; //initial text box count
  var $wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var $add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  $add_button.click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $wrapper.append($(".row").eq(0).clone());
    }
  });
  $('.classSel').on('change', function() {
    var thisClass = $(this).val(),
      $thisSection = $(this).closest("div").next().find("select");
    if (thisClass) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'get_sections.php',
        data: 'id=' + thisClass,
        success: function(html) {
          $thisSection.html(html);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $thisSection.html('<option value="">Select Class first</option>');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I of course cannot test if my snippet works - I do not have the rest of your code running on my machine. You have to run it and tell me WHAT does not work - any console errors? Perhaps I spelled something wrong

Comment: I changed the line **$wrapper.append($(".row").eq(0).clone());** to **$wrapper.append($(".row").eq(10).clone());** to get the cloning portion right

Comment: Sure. I cannot see which ROW is the one to clone. I saw only ONE row in the code in your question

Comment: $(".input_fields_wrap>.row") would possibly also work

Comment: Ok now I'm getting the same section values as the 1st instance which is being cloned

Comment: I assume that is what you wanted?

Comment: yes i wanted the same effect but the problem is that it is cloning exact same class sections and they remain same for the next instances **For Example** 1st Instance Class:1 has Sections: A & B, if I press Add Class btn and Select Class:4, then it also shows Sections: A & B whereas it has 3 Sections: A, B & C

Comment: What I saw was `<?php $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM classes "); $rowCount = $query->num_rows;` in both cases

Comment: I didn't understand what u meant by the above query, what about it?

Comment: You have the same query in the html part as in the jQuery part. It should return the exact same list of classes

Comment: Yes the classes will remain the same, what i meant was that the Sections should be according to the Selected Class, whereas I'm getting the same sections for other added classes as the 1st selected class

Comment: i have added the whole code in my question please check the **get_sections.php** portion, it has the Sections query

Comment: I know. If the classes are the same in the HTML and in the jQuery part, then I do not see how you would get other sections

Comment: the classes used are just for styling, nothing else, you mean the **form-control** class?

Comment: `<?php
            include('dbConfig.php');
            $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM classes ");
            $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
        ?>` is the same query as 

`<option value="">Select Class</option><?php $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM classes "); $rowCount = $query->num_rows;`

Comment: yes this query will remain the same as I have to fetch the classes first & then according to that selected class, the Sections shall appear